# BATCH Comparing two folders recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file

i'm updating a big save script and i need to compare 2 folders recursively. I think i'm pretty close but can't understand what's missing...

The code is the following :

```
set Rep1=f:\album1
set Rep2=f:\album2
set logfile=f:\logfile.txt
for /r "%Rep1%\" %%i in (*) do (
    fc "%%i" "%Rep2%\%%~nxi"
    iF ERRORLEVEL == 1 echo "%%i" et "%Rep2%\%%~nxi" Sont differents  >>  %logfile%
    iF ERRORLEVEL == 2 echo "%%i" et "%Rep2%\%%~nxi" Un des fichier est manquant >> %logfile%
)
pause
```

The problem is that it compares all files like `f:\album1\folder1\file1.txt` with `f:\album2\file1.txt` so the comparing is always wrong... You can see the result in the picture:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ9qt.png]

If any of you find a solution, thank you a lot !

Vincs

Comment: Don't know if that's usefull for you, but you also could check the md5 sum by `for /r %%f in (*) do md5.exe %%f >> output`

Comment: Are you really working with **DOS** (an OS from the 1980's)? I assume you are actually using Windows, so I adapted the tags accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
  SET "foundfile="
  FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN (
   'dir /s /b /a-d "%targetdir%\%%~nxa" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
   SET foundfile=Y
   FC /b "%%a" "%%c" >NUL
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO different "%%a" "%%c"
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED foundfile ECHO missing   "%%a" from "%targetdir%"
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%targetdir%\*" '
 ) DO (
  SET "foundfile="
  FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN (
   'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%~nxa" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
   SET foundfile=Y
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED foundfile ECHO missing   "%%a" from "%sourcedir%"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

One problem with your approach is that the file `%%i` is compared to "%Rep2%\%%~nxi" which means only in `%rep2%`, not in the subdirectory.

Another problem is

```
IF ERRORLEVEL == 1 echo "%%i" et "%Rep2%\%%~nxi" Sont differents  >>  %logfile%
```

which compares the literal string `ERRORLEVEL` to the literal string `1` so will not find a match. To use your method, you would have to turn `delayedexpansion` on with a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` statement and then use `IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 ...`

The solution posted above compares files that have the same name and extension wherever they are found on the tree, so if `file1.txt` is *anywhere* in the first tree, then it will be compared to *all* the `file1.txt` files found *anywhere* in the second tree.

Note also that there is a standard anomaly when dealing with a standard system that gives files both a long and a short name. Each file potentially has two names - and `dir` matches on *either* name.

Comment: I'm afraid this approach will fail if any of the trees (source and/or target) contain equally names files... +1 though because the basic idea is great!

Answer (score 0):

[Magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653942) already points out the major problems of your code.

However, the solution he provided uses only the file names for finding the files to compare, so it will fail if files with equal names occur at different locations in the source and target directories, or if multiple files with equal names occur within any of the directory trees.

Here is a similar solution, based on the `dir /S` command, which also requires each file name in the trees to be unique and to occur at the same location within source and target (it does not check for files present in only one of the source or target trees):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Provide source and target directory paths here:
set "SOURCE=.\source"
set "TARGET=.\target"

rem Convert relative paths to absolute ones:
for %%D in ("%SOURCE%") do set "SOURCE=%%~fD"
for %%D in ("%TARGET%") do set "TARGET=%%~fD"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('
    2^> nul dir /B /S /A:-D "%SOURCE%\*.*"
') do (
    set "SRC=%%~fI"
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('
        2^> nul dir /B /S /A:-D "%TARGET%\%%~nxI"
    ') do (
        set "TRG=%%~fJ"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        > nul fc /B "!SRC!" "!TRG!" || echo "!SRC!" and "!TRG!" differ.
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This code snippet compares only files which occur in both source and target directory trees. If respective files are different, a related message is returned.

---

To overcome the issue with equal file names at different locations, let us use the `xcopy /L` command, because this is capable of returning a list of paths relative to the source directory (the `/L` option prevents `xcopy` from copying any files; the appended `find` command filters out the `? File(s)` summary lines):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Provide source and target directory paths here:
set "SOURCE=.\source"
set "TARGET=.\target"

rem Convert relative paths to absolute ones:
for %%D in ("%SOURCE%") do set "SOURCE=%%~fD"
for %%D in ("%TARGET%") do set "TARGET=%%~fD"

pushd "%SOURCE%"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('
    2^> nul xcopy /L /S /Y ".\*.*" "%TEMP%\" ^| find ".\"
') do (
    set "SRC=%%~fI"
    pushd "%TARGET%"
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('
        2^> nul xcopy /L /Y "%%~I" "%TEMP%\" ^| find ".\"
    ') do (
        set "TRG=%%~fJ"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        > nul fc /B "!SRC!" "!TRG!" || echo "!SRC!" and "!TRG!" differ.
        endlocal
    )
    popd
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

This code snippet also compares only files which occur in both source and target directory trees. If you also want to check whether each fils is present in both source and target trees, check out [Magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653942) which provides a good idea of how to accomplish that (two-loop approach).